# getElementById no React/JSX

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Iniciei meus estudos de React ontem então não tenho muito conhecimento sobre, e gostaria de saber como dar um `document.getElementById()` em React/JSX, como faço isso?

Tentei usar `document.getElementById()` como disse e tentei tbm `App.getElementById()`, mas n deu certo nenhum dos 2 jeitos...

Tenho o seguinte código no meu App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/header';
import Input from './components/inputNum';
import Btn from './components/button';

function getURL() {
    var url = App.getElementById("input-url").value;
    console.log(url);
}

const App = () => 
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="content">
            <h1>Vídeos</h1>
            <Input id="input-url"></Input>
            <div className="button-container">
                <Btn onClick={getURL} id="btn-geturl"></Btn>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

No React, não utilizamos getElementById ou nenhum acesso direto ao DOM.

Para isso, você pode utilizar o estado do React:

O `useState`. Você define um array, e irá fazer uma desestruturação do valor retornado ao executar o método useState. Você pode passar um valor inicial para esse estado, como por exemplo:

`const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://google.com")`

A primeira variável é o valor em sí. A segunda é uma função, que você irá utilizar para alterar o valor.

No input, você informará que o `value` tem o valor da primeira variável, e informará no método onChange, que pegará o valor dentro do evento e alterará o valor do estado, dessa forma

`event => setUrl(event.target.value)`

O componente completo ficaria assim:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  function getURL() {
    console.log("url: ", url);
  }

  <div className="App">
    <div className="content">
      <h1>Vídeos</h1>
      <input value={url} onChange={event => setUrl(event.target.value)} />
      
      <button type="button" onClick={getURL}>Pegar URL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas de resolver isso seria criar um componente com state. Você poderia criar uma variável no state e guardar no state o valor do "input-url" quando ele for alterado. Desta forma, ao clicar no botão e executar a função "getUrl", você pegaria o valor armazenado no state. Pegando o seu código, ele teria que ser alterado, já que ele está como um "stateless component".

O seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from './components/header';
import Input from './components/inputNum';
import Btn from './components/button';


export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    url: ""
  };
  
  getURL = e => {
    var url = this.state.url;
    console.log(url);
  }
  
  alterar = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };


   render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="content">
            <h1>Vídeos</h1>
            <Input name="url" id="input-url" onChange={this.alterar}></Input>
            <div className="button-container">
                <Btn onClick={this.getURL} id="btn-geturl"></Btn>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )}
}
```

Comment: Ja há a possibilidade de usar os Hooks no react, como o o uso do useState. Não há mais a necessidade de criar classes.

Answer (score -1):

No React mais novo nao há necessidade de implementação de classes, e ficou um tanto mais facil usar o hook `useState`!

Exemplo->

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Dashboard = React.FC ()=>{
    const [name,setName] = useState('');
    return (
        <input onChange(e => setName(e.target.value)) />
    )
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Como viu o `name` é uma constante, e  o `setName` serve para setar o valor ou um novo valor para essa constante. O `useState()` recebe dentro dos parenteses o valor inicial da variavel, nesse caso uma string vazia.
Toda a vez que o input sofrer mudanças essas mudanças vao ser setas na variavel name atraves do `setName` e fiz uso de uma `arrow function` mas poderia ser chamado uma função também. O valor do `input` estará dentro do `.target.value`.

Answer (score -1):

//No exemplo acima....

import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Dashboard = React.FC ()=>{
const [name,setName] = useState('');
return (
<input onChange{(e => setName(e.target.value))} />
)
}
export default Dashboard;

//No meu só funcionou quando coloquei as chaves depois do onChange...